# Should I avoid deploying package.json or bower.json files to production?

Tags: web-application, javascript, information-gathering

I know it is recommended to hide OS and server version information when serving up web pages. What about js library version info contained in package.json or bower.json files? It seems like this could be used to create attacks by looking at known vulnerabilities. However, I know ultimately that a user could figure this out on their own just by looking at the files, so is it worth it?

EDIT:
I'm also interested in what is standard practice, regardless of security concerns.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - do you mean exposing package.json to the internet at large, or do you mean having the package.json file there on the production server? E.g. which exploit scenario are you worried about?

Comment: I'm worried about someone easily accessing the version numbers of js libraries and then using that info to create attacks based on known vulnerabilities in those libraries. The information is already available by looking through the js files themselves, but I wasn't sure what standard practice was. It seems like people include them but that doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allowing access to your package.json and similar files is going to be a bit of information disclosure and as such should generally be avoided.  In a scenario where a JS library had a known vulnerability, leaving this accessible in the web root would allow attackers to quickly assemble a list of valid targets.

It's unlikely to be a very high risk issue, but the general principle of not providing information to attackers holds, so I'd say that it shouldn't be placed into production in a form that's accessible to end-users.

In terms of standard practice to address this risk.  Typically either strip these files as part of the deployment process, or using something like .htaccess to prevent access to them.